# Select items in 0/1 knapsack ,where two items have same benefits |maximize value and minimize weight

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

In 0/1 knapsack problem, how do I select items, if two items have same value. The value with the lesser weight should be selected , how do I check that condition? I have the following function using Dynamic programming.

```
static int[] knapsack(int maxWeight, double[] weight, double[] value, int n) {
    //n = no. if items
    int i, w;

    double array[][] = new double[n + 1][maxWeight + 1];
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        for (w = 0; w <= maxWeight; w++) {
            if (i == 0 || w == 0)
                array[i][w] = 0;
            else if (weight[i - 1] <= w)
                array[i][w] = max(value[i - 1] + array[i - 1][(w -(int) weight[i - 1])], array[i - 1][w]);
            else
                array[i][w] = array[i - 1][w];
            if (i != 0 || w != 0)
                System.out.print(array[i][w] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    int[] selected = new int[n + 1];
    for (int j = n, wt = maxWeight; j > 0; j--) {   
        if (array[j][wt] != array[j - 1][wt]) {
            if (array[j][wt] == array[j][wt - 1]) {
                selected[j] = 0;
                break;
            }
            selected[j] = 1;
            wt = wt - (int) weight[j - 1];
        }
        else
            selected[j] = 0;
    }
    /** Print finally selected items **/
    System.out.println("\nItems selected : ");
    for (int k = 1; k < n + 1; k++)
        if (selected[k] == 1)
            System.out.print(k +" ");
        System.out.println();

        return selected;
}
```

For this type of case : (i,v): (4,45)(3,20)(5,30)(2,45) ,maxWeight = 5;
 where item 1 and 4 have same value, it should select the item with lesser weight that is 4th. how do I implement this condition in above code.
Problem statement :

> Your goal is to determine which things to put into the
>   package so that the total weight is less than or equal to the package
>   limit and the total cost is as large as possible. You would prefer to
>   send a package which weights less in case there is more than one
>   package with the same price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to **maximise value** with minimising **Weight** . You can check that

Let DP[i][j] be the maximal value that can be obtained!

And W[i][j] the minimal weight that is to be used!!

Then,

```
if(Current Weight > Element's Weight)
{
      if(DP[i-1][j-Weight[i]]+Value[i]>DP[i-1][j]){
             DP[i][j]=DP[i-1][j-Weight[i]]+Value[i];
             Weight[i][j]= Weight[i-1][j-Weight[i]]+Value[i]
      }
      else if(DP[i-1][j-Weight[i]]+Value[i] <  DP[i-1][j] ){
             DP[i][j]=DP[i-1][j];
             Weight[i][j]=Weight[i-1][j];
      } 
      else{                   //Note this is the tricky part elsewise the 
                              //Above conditions are simple Knapsack conditions

             DP[i][j]=DP[i-1][j];   //Both of them are equal We will get same Value . Thus we cannot maximise it in any other way!!
             Weight[i][j]=minimum ( Weight[i-1][j] ,Weight[i-1][j-Weight[i]]+A[i]);

      }
}
else
{
             DP[i][j]=DP[i-1][j];
             Weight[i][j]=Weight[i-1][j];
}
```

**Note** the solution is trivial unless the third condition in first if!
We need to maximise the fun at any cost! So we aren't Messing with it !
But when the fun from both cases is same , We need to pick the  one with lesser weight elsewise We will end up having more weight for same value of knapsack!

I have assumed you know knapsack 0/1 problem that is why I haven't explained first and second conditions !!

Comment: No, its not like i have to minimize weight all over.I have edited the question with problem statement. and if I remove items with same value with greater weight the DP won't maximize the value

Comment: @Ankita Did you see the complete Answer!! I have also answered the whole problem you mentioned as the other one was way more trivial!
Morover this problem is same as Party Schedule on Spoj(Online Judge) and I have solved it using the same Logic as described in my answer! Please Do see and accept to promote the effort in case the answer is correct!

Comment: I am accepting this answer as it solves  maximise value with minimising Weight , however I followed a different approach now to first sort the items in their ascending order of weight.

Comment: Sorting on the basis of weight would not ensure optimal cost that will have an issue!

Comment: @ShubhamSharma , do we need to use an additional array for weights? weight[][]

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to select the item with the lowest weight, then why not have it loop through the options and compare the weight of an `object[i]` with the weight of an object at `[i + 1]` if it is lower then just compare it to the next one, otherwise, `object[i] = object[i + 1]`, and so on. Did I understand the question correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Branch and Bound Algorithm` for it.

Sample code-

Considering Item is your POJO with weight and price.
Introduce a method `byRatio()` as follows-

```
 public static Comparator<Item> byRatio() {
        return (i1, i2) -> Double.compare(i2.calculateRatio(), i1.calculateRatio());
    }

public double calculateRatio() {
        return price / weight;
    }
```

This will help in sorting the list of items by ratio.

Let's write the core logic now -

```
 public List<Item> buildOptimalPackageWithBBAlgo(List<Item> items, double maxWeight) {
        items.sort(Item.byRatio());
        Node optimal = fetchOptimalNode(items, maxWeight);
        return optimal.items;
    }

 /**
     * This method used Branch and bound algorithm to search for the
     * optimal node.
     *
     * @param  items  sorted items by ratio of price to weight
     * @param  maxWeight maximum weight the package is allowed to hold
     * @return optimal node
     */
private Node fetchOptimalNode(List<Item> items, double maxWeight) {
    Node optimal = new Node();
    Node root = new Node();
    root.calculateBound(items, maxWeight);

    PriorityQueue<Node> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
    queue.offer(root);

    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        Node node = queue.poll();

        if (node.bound > optimal.price && node.height < items.size() - 1) {

            Node edgeNode = new Node(node);
            Item item = items.get(node.height);
            edgeNode.weight += item.getWeight();

            if (edgeNode.weight <= maxWeight) {

                edgeNode.items.add(items.get(node.height));
                edgeNode.price += item.getPrice();
                edgeNode.calculateBound(items, maxWeight);

                if (edgeNode.price > optimal.price) {
                    optimal = edgeNode;
                }
                if (edgeNode.bound > optimal.price) {
                    queue.offer(edgeNode);
                }
            }

            Node leafNode = new Node(node);
            leafNode.calculateBound(items, maxWeight);

            if (leafNode.bound > optimal.price) {
                queue.offer(leafNode);
            }
        }
    }
    return optimal;
}

private class Node implements Comparable<Node> {

    public int height;
    List<Item> items;
    public double bound;
    public double price;
    public double weight;

    public Node() {
        items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Node(Node parent) {
        height = parent.height + 1;
        items = new ArrayList<>(parent.items);
        bound = parent.bound;
        price = parent.price;
        weight = parent.weight;
    }

    public int compareTo(Node other) {
        return (int) (other.bound - bound);
    }

    private void calculateBound(List<Item> items, double maxWeight) {
        int i = height;
        double w = weight;
        bound = price;
        Item item;
        do {
            item = items.get(i);
            if (w + item.getWeight() > maxWeight) break;
            w += item.getWeight();
            bound += item.getPrice();
            i++;
        } while (i < items.size());
        bound += (maxWeight - w) * (item.getPrice() / item.getWeight());
    }
}
```

**Limitations** - This logic works only for items more than 2.
For less than 2 items, this is over engineering with respect to Time complexity.

Just use greedy algorithm approach for it.